# How to create linux user that would not require password to login with su?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to create a user that I would be able to login from a regular user without password prompt. How can I achieve this?

I'm trying to do the following:

```
$ sudo useradd test
$ sudo passwd -d test
```

And then try to run command as test:

```
$ su test id
Password
```

My Ubuntu distribution:

```
$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
Release:    19.04
Codename:   disco
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 5.0.0-35-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-022) (gcc version 8.3.0 (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1)) #38-Ubuntu SMP Sat Nov 9 17:51:58 UTC 2019
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why am I still asked for a password for a Linux user with a deleted password?

You may need to clear the password cache using:

```
sudo -k
```

> When used alone, the `-k (kill)` option to `sudo` invalidates the user's cached
>   credentials.

[sudo(8): execute command as another user - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo)

---

#### I want to create a user that I would be able to login from a regular user without password prompt.

> - Run command:
>
>   ```
>   sudo visudo
>   ```
>
>   Depending on what Linux distro you are using, and whether or not you have ever run visudo before, you may or may not get a prompt
>     asking you about what text editor you want to use to edit the sudoers
>     file. If you are unsure what to pick, I would suggest using nano.
> - Go down to the bottom of the file, add the following line:
>
>   ```
>   <user> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
>   ```
>
>   Note: replace `<user>` with your username
> - Save and exit the file
> - Run command:
>
>   ```
>   sudo -k
>   ```
>
>   This will clear the existing password cache
> - You're done!
> - To test, run command:
>
>   ```
>   sudo ls
>   ```
>
>   You should not be prompted for a password

Source [Jon's Site - Remove sudo Password Prompt](http://jonmoore.duckdns.org/index.php/linux-articles/58-remove-sudo-password-prompt)

---

#### Further Reading

- [Identity Crisis! (Account Permissions) SOLVED - Linux Mint Forums](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=208295)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I don't need my test user be a sudoer. I just want to be able to run some tasks under this test user. To make it easier to do from script I don't want and don't need password at all. I need to do it like: `su test mycommand`. Is it possible?

Comment: The problem is that I'd like to run su from regular user, not root or sudoer.

Comment: @MityaXMitya - please post your solution.